# SOQL query to load all documents in a content library

Tags: soql, bulk-api, contentdocument

I am trying to query for all the documents in a library using the BULK API. The SOQL query I use is

```
SELECT ContentDocument.Id,ContentDocument.CreatedDate,ContentDocument.LastModifiedDate,ContentDocument.IsDeleted,ContentDocument.SystemModstamp,ContentDocument.Title,ContentWorkspace.Name 
FROM ContentWorkspaceDoc
```

This will give me all the information for the latest version of each document. When I execute this query via the BULK API I get an error -

'InvalidBatch : Failed to process query: FUNCTIONALITY_NOT_ENABLED: Foreign Key Relationships not supported in Bulk Query'

What should SOQL query (usable with the BULK API) be for fetching document from a content library?

Comment: What if you'll try to cheat? `SELECT Id,CreatedDate,LastModifiedDate,IsDeleted,SystemModstamp,Title
FROM ContentDocument
WHERE Id IN (SELECT ContentDocumentId FROM ContentWorkspaceDoc WHERE ContentWorkspace.Name = 'Salesforce.com Training')`?

Answer (score 1):

It seems SOQL queries with relationships are not supported in Bulk API.

There is an idea posted [here](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000h6C2AAI)

Comment: Ya, I did read that but was wondering if there is another query/way to achieve what I want